# NSXMLparse to pull specific values from a long string.(Couple Questions.)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encryption, nsxmlparser

Excuse me if this is a question that has been asked before, if so point me to the right answer.(i couldn't find the answer.)

My Question's:

I have an XML coming in from a NSUrl i need to be able to parse it appropriately,
i will be receiving the responses with Field Perpetrators in them such as ().

Could i have it set up to search a dictionary for Keywords and parse them from the XML?
If so what would be a good start on learning that?

Also is it possible to save the response's and encrypt them until i need to use them in another view? 
if so, what is the best way to encrypt on the IOS side?

any guide in the right direction is wonderful!!
I'm not asking for someone to answer all of them but it would be nice, thank you!

Comment: Probably best to ask separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr`
has `NSDataWritingFileProtection` options that will encrypt the data for you but you have no control over they encryption key.

For encryption use CommonCrypro (part of iOS), aes128, cbc.  But the real question is how will you securely save the encryption key?

Here is an encryption/decryption method:

```
+ (NSData *)doCipher:(NSData *)dataIn
                  iv:(NSData *)iv
                 key:(NSData *)symmetricKey
             context:(CCOperation)encryptOrDecrypt
{
    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus   = kCCSuccess;
    size_t          cryptBytes = 0;    // Number of bytes moved to buffer.
    NSMutableData  *dataOut    = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dataIn.length + kCCBlockSizeAES128];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt( encryptOrDecrypt, // kCCEncrypt or kCCDecrypt
                       kCCAlgorithmAES128,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                       symmetricKey.bytes, 
                       kCCKeySizeAES128,
                       iv.bytes,
                       dataIn.bytes,
                       dataIn.length,
                       dataOut.mutableBytes,
                       dataOut.length,
                       &cryptBytes);

    if (ccStatus != kCCSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"CCCrypt status: %d", ccStatus);
    }

    dataOut.length = cryptBytes;

    return dataOut;
}
```

Comment: so would that be possible to save using the REST method?

Comment: You can save the encrypted data in the apps document directory with - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
 or to a URL with - (BOOL)writeToURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSDataWritingOptions)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr.

Comment: how does this work exactly, i do see your telling it if its not successful then not to show the data. other then that i don't understand, how does this keep my Data Secure as i will be working with Credit Card information.Sorry, still Pretty new to IOS.

Comment: If you are working with Credit Card information you really need to get help from a crypto expert in the payments field.  There are many requirements starting with PCI (https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/).  Security is a lot harder than it appears, the encryption part is the easy part.

Comment: i know all the Security needs, I'm working in alliance with PCI, and Verified by VISA. if you could point me in the direction to a more in depth Explanation of CommonCrypro that would be wonderful. I'm having more trouble in the matter of what to do when i receive the data as I'm not suppose to save it but i need to be able to parse it out and expose of all Data after words but also allow batching and so on and so forth.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/CC_crypto.3cc.html